# Is this good SQL query for resources?

Tags: sql

I have these sql query (I use codeigniter db class):

```
        $query = $this->db->select("a.title AS articles_title, 
                    a.content AS articles_content,
                    a.excerpt AS articles_excerpt,
                    a.slug AS articles_slug,
                    a.views AS articles_views,
                    a.views AS articles_views,
                    CONCAT(up.first_name, ' ', up.last_name) AS articles_author,
                    DATE_FORMAT(a.created, '%T %d.%m.%Y') AS articles_created, 
                    (SELECT IF(ROUND(AVG(av.vote),1), ROUND(AVG(av.vote),1), 0)  FROM articles_votes av WHERE a.id = av.article_id) AS articles_votes,
                    (SELECT COUNT(ac.id) FROM articles_comments ac WHERE a.id = ac.article_id) AS articles_totalcomments", FALSE)
            ->from('articles a')
            ->join('user_profiles up', 'a.author_id = up.user_id')
            ->where('page_id', $page_id)
            ->order_by("a.$ordering")
            ->get();
```

Is it good for resources of server and speed? Or should I create another function for counting votes and comments, which will count all comments and average vote and afterwill add it to the array of articles?

Thank you

Comment: of course it is not an efficient query as it uses multiple sub-queries.

Answer (score 0):

Resources used and the efficiency of the query plan depend on the underlying database and, of course, the actual SQL that is generated. It's always good to use a SQL profiling tool to make sure you understand how the query actually turns out.

That said. You can sometimes get better performance turning something like this:

```
SELECT 
   a.student_id, 
   a.name, 
   (select sum(s.score) from scores s where s.student_id = a.student_id) as total_score
FROM students a
```

To something like this:

```
SELECT
   a.student_id,
   a.name,
   tot.score
FROM students a
JOIN (
   SELECT student_id, 
          sum(score)
   FROM scores 
   GROUP BY student_id
) as tot ON tot.student_id = a.student_id
```

If your column expression involves a query on an un-indexed column, it may require a full table scan everytime it is run. In my example, I'm including a key in the join results so it the query is done once, then you can get it in the outer select.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. So my solutions is better than solutions with two or more query and php foreach function, isn't it?